# Talend (Placing the Xls file in sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint, talend

I am quite new for the Talend tool.

I have the requirement to place the xls/.csv file in sharepoint application using Talend.

How can I achieve this and  which components we need to use to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `tFileFetch` component.

In the advanced settings enable `Upload File` option.

You can [refer this link](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tFileFetch)